# sh quit unexpectedly while using the dyld_sim plug-in

Tags: ios, xcode, shell

while using the Xcode(with shell script) to develope my app,i got shell crash everytime when Xcode try to run the script,below are the details

```
Process:               sh [2799]
Path:                  /bin/sh
Identifier:            sh
Version:               97
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        DPScope [2795]
Responsible:           launchd_sim [2129]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim
PlugIn Identifier:       dyld_sim
PlugIn Version:          ??? (353.2.1)

Date/Time:             2015-07-17 15:28:40.462 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        5B924542-907D-6B59-6852-DDC89E25663D


Time Awake Since Boot: 4300 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_SHARED_REGION=avoid
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/yxn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nova-ekcmoqanifjpjlhgyggebwsjyegu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib
DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/yxn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nova-ekcmoqanifjpjlhgyggebwsjyegu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulato

Dyld Error Message:
  program was built for Mac OS X and cannot be run in simulator

Binary Images:
       0x10bb5b000 -        0x10bbe0ff7  sh (97) <DE2DFF25-438A-3F54-9A91-93A369601FA1> /bin/sh
       0x10bbf9000 -        0x10bc1d77f +dyld_sim (353.2.1) <CA4A779A-BA45-39C7-9456-1B8A06818142> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim
    0x7fff6a68c000 -     0x7fff6a6c2837  dyld (353.2.1) <72A99D0F-0B56-3938-ABC5-67A0F33757C4> /usr/lib/dyld

Model: MacBookPro11,3, BootROM MBP112.0138.B15, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.19f12
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, PCIe, 2048 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.5f8 15969, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Network Service: Thunderbolt Ethernet, Ethernet, en4
Network Service: VPN (PPTP), PPP (PPTP), ppp0
PCI Card: Apple 57762-A0, Ethernet Controller, Thunderbolt@195,0,0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512F, 500.28 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
Thunderbolt Device: Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter, Apple Inc., 1, 5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

> Dyld Error Message:
>     program was built for Mac OS X and cannot be run in simulator

You should not build it for the architecture X86-64.